# stop Response.Redirect from encoding

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

The URL string generated after this response.redirect is causing us a headache. It is replacing the characters with url percent encoding characters and adding in extra file directories.

```
Response.Redirect("TestingReport.aspx?id=" + Request.QueryString("id") + "&Test_Type_ID=" + Request.QueryString("Test_Type_ID") + "&TType=" + Request.QueryString("TType"))
```

https://subdomain.domain.com/User%20Portal/Testing/%2fUser%2520Portal%2fTesting%2fTestingReport.aspx%3fid%3d8444%26Test_Type_ID%3d2%26TType%3dCore%20Mandatory%202

Why is it changing ? and = to the percent codes? I don't understand why it is appending User Portal/Testing twice either.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [URLEncoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm). Checkout [this online utility](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to decode the string you have.
In .NET, you can use `System.Web.HttpUtility` to encode/decode.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there in no empty space in your URL.

Answer (score 0):

The entire URL gets URL ecoded, which is probably because you are not URL encoding the values that you put in the string. URL encode the values properly, and it should work:

```
Response.Redirect(
  "TestingReport.aspx?id=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("id")) +
  "&Test_Type_ID=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("Test_Type_ID")) +
  "&TType=" + Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("TType"))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might want to build your query string separately from the Redirect method line, URL encode those values and then HTML encode the URL passed to Response.Redirect

Sample shown from MSDN website. I suspect that your concatenation operations are somehow causing the framework to URL encode the entire thing, rather than just the values.

```
<%
```

> dim qs

```
qs = Server.URLEncode(Request.Querystring) 

Response.Redirect "newpage.asp?" + Server.HTMLEncode(qs) 
%>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309.aspx

Comment: No, the entire query string should not be URL encoded, only the values, or you will be encoding the `&` separators. Also, the query string should not be HTML encoded. That's used when you put the URL in an attribute in HTML code, and then the entire attribute value should be HTML encoded, not just the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472150/response-redirect-occasionally-ignores-url-encoding). Basically .Net is trying to sanitize the URL for you and messing up. The solution is to manually encode it.