# Why is Response.Redirect UrlEncoding some parts of the well-formed URL it is supplied?

Tags: redirect, iis, asp-classic, urlencode

I have a tiny (Classic) ASP file being used for a redirect. I want to send the user to a URL that may have some characters in (I'm taking this from the incoming URL, as it's redirecting all paths from domainA to domainB, but I've hard-coded it here to simplify things).

Here's an example URL, as it comes to the the redirect script:

`https://old.example.org/my%20test/?name=Danny%20Tuppeny`

The URL contains two spaces, which I am certain are both encoded correctly. If you paste the URL into your browser with literal spaces, both will be converted to `%20` by the browser.

I'm passing this url to `Response.Redirect` (hard-coded here for simplicity):

```
<%
Response.Redirect "https://new.example.org/my%20test/?name=Danny%20Tuppeny"
%>
```

However the location header being output has **one of** the %20's encoded again, and looks like this:

`Location: https://new.example.org/my%2520test/?name=Danny%20Tuppeny`

This is unexpected! This has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511915/stop-response-redirect-from-encoding) but all answers (including the excepted one) appear to be incorrect. I do not believe I should be randomly decoding parts of a valid URL to offset what appears to be unexpected/undesirable behavior from ASP.

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(v=vs.90).aspx) make no mention of this behavior (they even say "Always validate and encode the URL that is passed to Response.Redirect"), and even worse, have samples on how to apply *HTML* encoding to values being passed to `Response.Redirect` which seems even more incorrect.

**Note:** ASP.NET does *not* have this stupid behaviour.

Is there a way to pass a well-formed URL to `Response.Redirect` and have it do what is expected?

Answer (score 2):

To work around the encoding issue you can add a Location header to perform the redirection. No encoding will be applied to the URL.

```
Response.Status = "302 Moved Temporarily"  ''// or use whatever status code is appropriate
Response.AddHeader "Location", "https://new.example.org/my%20test/?name=Danny%20Tuppeny"
```

Comment: That's what I've done; though I was hoping to understand why Response.Redirect is doing what it is.  Is there some world where its behaviour would make sense?